# Routing PythonAnywhere script through Australia using 'ssh SOCK proxy'

Tags: python, ssh, socks, pythonanywhere

I have a python script which I want to run on PythonAnywhere in the cloud. The script runs correctly on my local computer, but will not run on PythonAnywhere as the server is hosted in US, and this task cannot be done in the US.

As such I would like to make it look like the script is coming from Australia, like a VPN (apologies for the poor choice of language). I have been told this is possible by creating a 'ssh SOCKS proxy'. My questions are:

1. How can I find out how to do this?
2. Are there any security concerns involved in this? For instance, if this task involves sending a password and logging on to a website, is there a chance someone could get my details?
3. How do I pick Australia specifically to be where the script is routed through?
4. Is there an better/easier option?

Comment: 6 years later, no need to create a SOCKS proxy, you can buy Australian proxy access and connect your app via that.